# What do the last bytes in the hex-dump of the Git Index file represent?

Tags: git

My index file's dump version in HEX format is;

```
xxd .git/index

00000000: 4449 5243 0000 0002 0000 0001 65de 84a1  DIRC........e...
00000010: 1542 02a2 65de 84a1 1542 02a2 0000 0801  .B..e....B......
00000020: 0020 062b 0000 81a4 0000 0000 0000 0000  . .+............
00000030: 0000 0029 81d6 227f 690d df0c 8a11 f7c9  ...)..".i.......
00000040: ef17 f274 bc04 fcea 000a 5245 4144 4d45  ...t......README
00000050: 2e65 6e63 0000 0000 0000 0000 7513 c39a  .enc........u...
00000060: 8a78 84f5 c369 7ee1 95f4 01ff 1fe7 bedd  .x...i~.........
```

According to Git documentation,

> "160-bit SHA-1 over the content of the index file before this
> checksum."

**The question-1:** What is the sha-1 of my index file? Is the last 20 byte of my hex-dump output? If not, which file's hash do the last 20 bytes represent? If it so, When I run this, it could not match;

```
git hash-object .git/index
-------
>> f0d0468a496b4cd29fd090e5d417639a7ce07bf8
------------------------
This is not matched with --> 7513 c39a 8a78 84f5 c369 7ee1 95f4 01ff 1fe7 bedd
```

**The question-2:** What do the 8 bytes before the last 20 bytes represent? Is this null terminated? If so, how many bytes can a Null byte be at most? **(if not, where is the my null-byte?)**

```
0000 0000 0000 0000  (before 7513 c39a 8a78 84f5 c369 7ee1 95f4 01ff 1fe7 bedd)
```

By the way, I know what the previous bytes are, I don't want to hear comments about the other bytes. These two things confused me.

Comment: According to https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/gitformat-index.txt#L43, the 8 bytes before that are two fields: a 32-bit extension signature, and a 32-bit extension length. Presumably an extension signature and length of zero corresponds to "no extension."

Comment: Note that git hash-object hashes the entire object, including the hash on the end. Tried removing the last 20 bytes of the file, but the resulting hash still does not match.

Comment: *What is the sha-1 of my index file?* You write it literally in the citation before this question.

Comment: Also note that the SHA-1 hash of a byte stream (file) *is not the same* as the SHA-1 that would be produced by `git hash-object`. The latter computes the SHA-1 of a stream that also contains a type specification and a length and is, therefore, different from the original byte stream.

Comment: For both cases, I still don't understand what this indicates? `7513 c39a 8a78 84f5 c369 7ee1 95f4 01ff 1fe7 bedd`, which file's hash value? @j6t

Comment: The index file itself, but without the last 20 bytes, of course.

Comment: So, How can I prove it, because NickODell says; "Tried removing the last 20 bytes of the file, but the resulting hash still does not match. " @j6t

Comment: @NickODell used `git hash-object`, but it does not produce the SHA-1 of the bytes, but something else, as I have explained in my earlier comment. Use `sha1sum` instead.

Comment: @NickODell,so in here, .... the 8 bytes before that are two fields: a 32-bit extension signature, and a 32-bit extension length ..., is ok but then this came to my mind, in here whats the my null byte?

Answer (score 2):

`git hash-object` does *not* generate a SHA1 hash of arbitrary bytes. It generates the following output: `SHA1(type(object) + ' ' + str(length(bytes(object))) + '\0' + bytes(object))`.

It's the `sha1sum` of the index file's content. The content does *not* include the checksum itself:

> Hash checksum over the content of the index file before this checksum.
> — [git.git:Documentation/gitformat-index.txt](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/gitformat-index.txt)

```
$ git init
$ touch empty
$ git add empty
$ wc -c .git/index 
104 .git/index
$ dd if=.git/index bs=1 count=$((104-20)) 2>/dev/null | sha1sum
056255b20de9a2f9e75c669934bf3a8a60be7a21  -
$ dd if=.git/index bs=1 skip=$((104-20)) 2>/dev/null | xxd -p
056255b20de9a2f9e75c669934bf3a8a60be7a21

$ git hash-object empty
e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391
$ pigz -d - < .git/objects/e6/9de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391 | sha1sum
e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391  -
$ pigz -d - < .git/objects/e6/9de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391 | xxd
00000000: 626c 6f62 2030 00                        blob 0.

$ sha1sum < empty
da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709  -
```

Shameless plug: If you are interested in all the low-level details, you can browse the [slide deck of a presentation I gave in 2019](https://fhlug.at/%7Edkf/git-deep-dive.deck/) on how Git stores objects in binary format. It even has a section about the binary index format.